Exclude scrollbar from mask-image
I have an horizontal menu with mask image at the edges, however the scrollbar is included in the mask and the edges are faded, How do I create another mask on the lower part of the div to show the scrollbar completely?
I tried using mask-size for the bottom part but the scrollbar is totally hidden.
  mask-size: 100% 85%;
  mask-position: top;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;



.nav {
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 3%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 97%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
}
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="menu">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</nav>



